# Impose build order for a multi-project in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a multi project in maven like this:

```
paren-project
  -> plugin-project
  -> testbed-project
```

The `plugin` project generates a JAR, which is manually copied to a specific subdirectory of `testbed` (using whatever embedded script like [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) or [ant](/questions/tagged/ant)). The important point: I don't want the plugin JAR to be in the classpath of testbed.

But I cannot found the solution to force the plugin project to be build BEFORE the testbed project. If I set the plugin project as dependency of the testbed project, it is added in the classpath.

Any solution, or do I have to switch to a build system like [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle), [ivy](/questions/tagged/ivy) or [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As it is mentioned at the http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

> **Reactor Sorting**
>
> ```
> Because modules within a multi-module build can depend on each other, 
> it is important that The reactor sorts all the projects in a way that 
> guarantees any project is built before it is required.
>
> The following relationships are honoured when sorting projects:
> ```
>
> 1. project dependency on another module in the build
> 2. plugin declaration where the plugin is another modules in the build
> 3. plugin dependency on another module in the build
> 4. build extension declaration on another module in the build
> 5. *the order declared in the modules element (if no other rule applies)*
>
> Note that only "instantiated" references are used - dependencyManagement 
>   and pluginManagement elements will not cause a change to the reactor sort order

Comment: Thank you, I declare no relationship and succeed to build the plugins before the testbed by declaring them before the module testbed.

Comment: This deserves some clarification.  We've found that rule #5 only applies if the given module order is totally compatible with rules #1-#4.  So you cannot use it to say "A before B" unless you also establish a correct global module build order that doesn't violate any dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

Maven is a versatile system. No need to switch.

You can add the dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group</groupId> 
  <artifactId>artifact</artifactId> 
  <optional>true</optional> 
</dependency>
```

This way, the dependency will not be included in the classpath.

Read more about [Optional Dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Comment: Optional is about transitive relationship, no use for this problem.

Comment: This worked for me with a slightly different problem.  i had Integration tests in one project that output resources to be used in tests by another.  i scoped the dependency to test only so that i would include the war in the build.  For this purpose this worked great.

Comment: Kartoch, according to the documentation, the optional dependency does not included in the classpath, but changes the classification of the reactor. then the solution is valid.

Comment: This may have undesirable side-effects, like including the module in a shaded artifact even though it is not a true dependency, although the comment suggesting setting <scope>test</scope> is clever.