# Maven one pom to run many pom

Tags: java, maven

I'm sure there is an answer here, but I searched for the title and yielded nothing. Google was similarly unhelpful.

I have many projects in intelij, each with their own pom. They also have a parent-pom, that runs all of them.

I would like another pom that runs 4 specific projects in a set order. How do I do this?

Alternatively, in intellij can i just make a run command that just runs the 4 poms in order - that would be ideal.

Edit - the "possible duplicate", while I have no doubts exists, is definitely not what ever has been proposed.

Comment: Can you make a script to kick off what you need done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build order of Maven multimodule project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131575/build-order-of-maven-multimodule-project)

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for one pom to rule them all, one pom to find them; one pom to bring them all and in the darkness bind them? This sounds useful and tempting but I feel I must warn of the severe side effects.

Comment: Can't you make use of `--projects` option? From the directory of root pom file `mvn clean install --projects a,b,c,d`

Comment: One possible option could be to use separate maven profiles for such runs.
If you need to run specific projects regardless of maven multimodule reactor behaviour you can use IntelliJ Run Configuration 'Before launch' section and add there 4 specific maven commands in the order you need.