# maven dependency not visible for importing

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, multi-module

i have a multimodule project and in one of this module I include dependency, some are visibile the other not; try to explain better:

i have this module in parent pom:

```
    <modules>
        <module>DataModelIbm</module>
        <module>commonResources</module>
        <module>wsdlClient</module>
        <module>utente</module>
  </modules>
```

in the pom of the module utente I have:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>dc.ita.int.gu</groupId>
        <artifactId>DataModelIbm</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dc.ita.int.gu</groupId>
        <artifactId>commonResources</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dc.ita.int.gu.wes</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdlClient</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </dependency>
```

In the project of Utenti, I import:

from module DataModelIbm

```
import dc.ita.int.gu.database.model.GuUserCon;
import dc.ita.int.gu.database.model.GuUserNon;
```

from commonResources:

```
import dc.ita.int.gu.errorhandler.ErrDetails;
```

from wsdlClient

```
import dc.ita.int.gu.wes.websso.wsdl.CreateUserResponse;
import dc.ita.int.gu.wes.websso.wsdl.GetUser;
```

But when I try to compile there is error only on the class imported from wsdlClient;

What can be the reason, is maven bug???

Answer (score 1):

I think it is an issue with the order used to build the modules

[Build order of Maven multimodule project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131575/build-order-of-maven-multimodule-)
project

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't sound like a Maven bug. As a starting point, open a command shell in the `utente` module and run `mvn dependency:tree` to check your dependencies to make sure that you are importing the `wsdlClient` module properly. Also, since wsdl-related code is often autogenerated, check the source code to make sure that everything is proper with class visibility expressions, packages, etc. Without seeing the error message, going through this checklist is the most help that can be given unfortunately.