# How to add a maven plugin dependency in build of a submodule as another submodule in the same project without executing mvn install?

Tags: maven

I have a parent maven module `parent` as follows :

```
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<modules>
<module>c1</module>
<module>c2</module>
</modules>
```

`c1` is a normal child module of the same version `0.0.1` of same group id `com`.

The `c2` module is of the same group id `com` and same version `0.0.1`, however, uses a plugin under build that has a dependency on c1 as follows:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com</groupId>
                <artifactId>c1</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

If I run `mvn install` on c1 and then run `mvn package` on parent then everything works fine.
However, I do not want to run mvn install on c1.
Is it possible to package it in a single command?

Comment: What happens if you just run `mvn clean package` on the parent? Which error do you get?

Comment: It tries to download the dependency `c1` from maven central and says dependency not found

Comment: Does it help to reverse the order of the modules in the parent POM, i.e. write `c2` first?

Comment: Generally, you case should be covered in the build order algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11131721/927493