# Maven force build order of project

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi module project like below

- Parent

  - Child1
  - Child2
  - Child3
  - Integration

The **Integration** project (pax-exam test) has references to Child1 and Child2, thus recator order will be:

- Child1
- Child2
- Integration
- Child3

but is required to have Child3 at runtime (osgi-bundle) and fails because Child3 isn't installed yet.

If I specify the Integration project last in my 's section in the parent pom everything works, but as soon as a new project is added it will be appended last in the  section and there will be fails all over again.

Is there anyway to force one project to be built/installed last, ie. overriding reactor order determined here http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html ?

I've tried failsafe plugin but the seems to only run integration tests after unit tests INSIDE current project and not the whole stack.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I don't want to add dependencies to Integration project each time a new child project is added just for the sake of getting the Integration project to install last. Then it's just easier to remember to move the Integration module last in list in parent pom modules section.

The dependencies is already taken care of with the features.xml file that is loaded from pax-exam.

Comment: You could try adding a dependency on Child3 in your Integration project with "provided" scope - perhaps that will trigger the correct build order.

Comment: Yeah it will but then I could instead move the integration test in module section in parent pom. I don't want to alter the project each time a new porject is added.

Comment: Hmmmm. Well, if there is a dependency between projects, it really ought to be stated in the POM file(s). Even if that requires work each time a project is added.

Comment: @Duncan the scope should be "runtime" not "provided" in this case I think.

Comment: @Puce Perhaps. I wasn't sure if OSGi was viewed as a container in Maven's eyes, thus meaning "provided" was correct: "*you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime*".

Comment: @Duncan In this case, the integration test is the container and has only the information provided by the pom.

Comment: @Duncan If you need OSGi framework functionality at compile time use "provided". If you need another bundle only at runtime use "runtime".

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies between projects should be handled in the dependency sections of the POM.

If you need a dependency only at runtime, not at compile time, then add

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

to the dependency declaration.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding Child3 to Integration dependencies (I suggest scope provided - which means include in the compile time, but don't include in runtime). Additionally if you don't want Child3 in Integration's transitive dependencies, you might add optional tag. Here is an example:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>someGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>Child3</artifactId>
        <version>someVersion</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>            
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Provided is wrong. Obviously, there are no compile time dependencies, or the project would not even compile. Runtime is correct, the dependency is only needed during the execution (which means the integration tests in this case). You could also choose "test" in this case.

Comment: @blackbuild yes, that's right. But I believe that both solutions will work, because the problem lies in reactor order. Am I right? However I admit - your is more descriptive.

Comment: Yes, both will work. However, your pom would "lie" about its dependencies. I always advice writing poms declaring intend first and effect second.

Comment: But then I need to add a dependency each time a new project is added. If I could only manage to install the integration module last then there wouldn't be any need of specifying dependencies in the pom.

Comment: @Marcus Yes that's right. Dependency is the strongest rule in Maven reactor ordering. Perhaps there some third party build extensions which might help you, but I haven't heard of any. You may find additional information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593503/impose-build-order-for-a-multi-project-in-maven and here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html